# Excel VBA setting range from string variable

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to set a range in a chart series collection from a public variable.  The data range is stored in another sheet in the following format.  Here is code I have also hard coded in my VBA sub to verify that the range is populating into the variable correctly and then converting to a range.  I get the same error either way.

```
    Public dataRange As String
    dataRange = "MyData!$F$2:$F$118,$H$2:$H$118"

    Dim rgnY As Range

    Set rngY = Range(dataRange)
```

But I get this error:

```
    Run-time error '1004' : Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed
```

I'm not sure why this is happening.  I've googled this error and although I see lots of suggestions I'm not sure how to fix in my case.  I need to populate a chart series values and XValues with data stored in this format.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you try adding the sheet name in front of both ranges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Range` object can refer to non-contiguous areas, but only where all are on the same sheet.  Here you are referring to `$F$2:$F$118` on sheet `MyData`, and `$H$2:$H$118` on the Active Sheet, which may or may not be `MyData`.  I'm guessing not since you get an error.

Assuming you intended both sub-ranges to be on `MyData` use

```
dataRange = "MyData!$F$2:$F$118,MyData!$H$2:$H$118"
```

Comment: That does get rid of the error, but what is interesting is if you print the address, `Debug.Print rgnY.Address(0, 0, 1, 1)` even with the `MyData!` in front of both it returns, `[Book1]MyData!F2:F118,H2:H118` Which in turn will return the same error if you try to use it.  If it is required why does it not return it that way?